# How can I plot live data using Folium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, geolocation, folium

I wrote a little script using Jupyter Notebook with the goal of live plotting the location of the International Space Station.

Here is the script:

```
import folium
import requests 
from time import sleep
#plot a base map
world = folium.Map(location=[0, 0],
                  tiles='Stamen Terrain',
                  zoom_start=2, detect_retina=True)
i = 0
while True:
    #get the data
    response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json")
    data = response.json()
    # parse the results 
    lat = data['iss_position']['latitude']
    long = data['iss_position']['longitude']
    print(lat, long)
    #show(lat, long) on the map
    folium.Circle(
        radius=1000,
        location=[lat, long], #use lat, long
        popup='International Space Station',
        color='red',
        fill=False,
        ).add_to(world)
    sleep(5)    
    world # does not work!
    i += 1
```

Questions: 
At the end of the loop I want to plot the map, but that does not work. How can plot the live location of the ISS on the map? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

(when I place `world` outside of the while loop, it works)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot dynamically update a map via new data with Folium (as for `Folium 0.10.1`) .

You should, for example, use [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#dynamiccustom-data-loading), instead.

Comment: Isn't Folium just a python wrapper for Leaflet?

Answer (score 1):

### Edit 05/03/2024

Folium [v0.16.0](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/releases/tag/v0.16.0) has been released with the leaflet-realtime plugin.

### Original Answer

On 2024-01-02 the leaflet-realtime plugin was [merged](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/pull/1848) to the Folium GitHub repo. This adds the ability to map data in real time (given an interval). Until Folium releases a new version you can install Folium yourself from their repo and play around with the Realtime plugin.

To track the location of the International Space Station (taken from [Realtime plugin user guide](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/user_guide/plugins/realtime.html)):

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import Realtime

m = folium.Map()

source = folium.JsCode("""
    function(responseHandler, errorHandler) {
        var url = 'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544';

        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json().then((data) => {
                var { id, longitude, latitude } = data;

                return {
                    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                    'features': [{
                        'type': 'Feature',
                        'geometry': {
                            'type': 'Point',
                            'coordinates': [longitude, latitude]
                        },
                        'properties': {
                            'id': id
                        }
                    }]
                };
            })
        })
        .then(responseHandler)
        .catch(errorHandler);
    }
""")

rt = Realtime(source, interval=10000)
rt.add_to(m)

m   # show in Jupyter
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you have idea how I can place markers and remove them is this now doable with folium ?

Comment: If you want automatic removal of markers then the realtime plugin that's in the answer is enough. If you want to remove markers by a different mechanism (e.g. by clicking on the marker to remove) I would check out [streamlit-folium](https://folium.streamlit.app/).